# How to change a pyglet image into a numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pyglet

I want to take screenshots and change it into a numpy array while my pyglet game is running ,how can i do it ?

using `pyglet.image.get_buffer_manager().get_color_buffer().get_image_data()`

I can take screenshot but I don't know how to change it into a numpy array.

by the way ,using function `get_data()` was so time consuming , i have tried that ,but it slows my game.